# Form launch in MS Access 2010 work, doesn't work in 2003

Tags: ms-access-2010, ms-access-2003

I have a database that has been developed in MS Access 2010. When it launches it uses the Current Database | Application Options | Display Form field to open the only form, then the OnOpen code in that form does its stuff.  Work just great.

I sent a copy of the DB to a user who complained he couldn't open it. After discovering that he's running Access 2003 (and won't be upgrading any time soon), I saved the DB in 2003 format as an .MDB file. Now I'm finding that the form isn't launching when he opens the database.

The last time I'd worked with Access (prior to my 2010 fun & games) was when Office products came with version numbers, not model years, so I'm not familiar with how to set up the form launch and/or AutoExec macro in the .MDB from within the 2010 interface.

**Opening the .MDB in 2010,** I select File |Options | Current Database, then look at Application Options | Display Form, and it still shows my desired form, but it's not opening, and the code in it isn't executing.

If someone could provide a brief walk through (or pointer to an existing one) of setting up an automatic form launch/Autoexec Macro for an Access 2003 .MDB via the Access 2010 interface I would be most appreciative.

I seem to be the only one on the web who has to go backwards - every other question I've seen is about moving code forward from 2003 to 2010.

**Edited for clarity**

Answer (score 0):

In 2003 you could set the opening form in Tools | Startup. 
In code just edit StartupForm property `currentdb.Properties("StartupForm")="Form.Form1"`
 or if it does not exist add :`set np=currentdb.CreateProperty("StartupForm",dbText,"Form.Form1")
currentdb.Properties.Append(np)`

Comment: What event does that go on? In 2010, the only way to get code to launch (that I'm familiar with) is to use the menu options to define which form opens on DB open, then use the `OnOpen` property of that form to start any setup work.

Comment: If you add the property when the mdb opens in 2003 it opens the form it is not attached to any event. If you don't have 2003 then add property in an immediate window.